# GCC Compile Error: "error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before..." from variadic macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I am attempting to work through the exercises in "Foundations of Computer Science, C Edition". The code below is directly from the book, but when I try to include and use it as they desctibe I get complier errors.

```
#define DefCell(EltType, CellType, ListType)
typedef struct CellType *ListType;
struct CellType {
    EltType element;
    ListType next;
};

/*************************************************
 *  DefCell(int, CELL, LIST);
 *
 *  expands to:
 *
 *  typedef struct CELL *LIST;
 *  struct CELL {
 *      int element;
 *      LIST next;
 *  }
 *
 *  as a consequence we can use CELL as the type of integer cells
 *  and we can use LISTas the type of pointers to these cells.
 *
 *  CELL c;
 *  LIST l;
 *
 * defines c to be a cell and l to be a pointer to a cell.
 * Note that the representation of a list of cells is normally
 * a pointer to the first cell on the list, or NULL if the list
 * is empty.
 *
 ****************************************************/
```

(The book can be downloaded for free - this code is on page 23.)

I have also tried to use the template to solve one of the exercises(2.2.3):

```
DefCell(char, LETTER, STRING);

BOOLEAN FirstString(STRING s1, STRING s2);
```

The errors I get are:

```
selectionsort.c:22:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘EltType’
selectionsort.c:60:28: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘s1’
selectionsort.c:133:28: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘s1’
```

I understand that the compiler doesn't know that STRING or EltType is a type, but what I don't understand is why not? The book is somewhat old, so it may be that C programming has moved on from the technique in the book. It is also possible I am just misunderstanding some key element of the idea they are presenting.
I'd really like to understand what I am doing wrong before I move on. Can anyone help?

Comment: Search on google [`Multiline macros in C`](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiline-macros-in-c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are "one-liners".

A new-line ends the macro.

One needs to tell the pre-processor that the line-break in the editor should not be treated as one. This is done by **ending** the line with a back-slash  (`\`).

So this

```
#define DefCell(EltType, CellType, ListType)
typedef struct CellType *ListType;
struct CellType {
  EltType element;
  ListType next; 
};
```

should be

```
#define DefCell(EltType, CellType, ListType) \
typedef struct CellType * ListType; \
struct CellType { \
  EltType element; \
  ListType next; \
};
```

Please note that to have this work **nothing** is allowed after the "line-terminating" back-slash.

---

And btw: `DefCell` **isn't a variadic** macro.

```
#define DefCell(E, C, L, ...)
```

would be one.

Answer (score 1):

The macro and the comment below it don't match up.

```
#define DefCell(EltType, CellType, ListType)
```

says that the preprocessor should just remove every instance of `DefCell(...)`.

If you want to define a macro over several lines, you need to include a backslash `\` at the end of each intermediate line

```
#define DefCell(EltType, CellType, ListType) \
    typedef struct CellType *ListType;       \
    struct CellType {                        \
        EltType element;                     \
        ListType next;                       \
    };
```